# Basic Nested Routes (how to have nested routes and not nested routes simultaneously)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have routes like this:

```
resources :users do
  resources :projects
end
```

I would like to be able to access routes like this:

```
/users/1/projects/1
```

and

```
/projects/1
```

Is this possible? How would I set this up? I'm having and issue in my app where we would like to have users able to see both their own projects via /users/:id/projects/:id but also on other pages we'd like to just see all the projects created, like this /projects or a project and an id, like this /projects/:id. I feel like I'm missing something, should I just get rid of the nested routes? Or can I have both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have both. Just add `resources :projects` to your routes.rb.
Then, in your ProjectsController you will have to do:

```
def index
  if params[:user_id]
    @projects = User.find(params[:user_id]).projects
  else
    @projects = current_user.projects
  end
end
```

I'm assuming your authentication system provides with `current_user` method for your controllers (as most of them do)

Comment: +1 i implemented this and it works fine... the one thing i don't like about it is that i realized a lot of my code ends up with conditionals checking for user_id. also in my views, a route like this users_project_path will break if there is no user, so i'd have to add more conditions... know any solution to this? thanks :)

Comment: If unifying both /projects and /users/:user_id/projects to the same controllers/views is too much of a hassle you could just send one of the routes to a different controller. You can do it with the :controller option of the routes for example;
`resources :projects, :controller => :current_user_projects`
or alternatively:
`resources :users do
  resources :projects, :controller => :user_projects
end`

Answer (score 2):

You can surely have both ways depending on your needs.

```
resources :users do
  resources :projects 
end
resources :projects
```

Will give you your url in /users/:user_id/projects/:id and in /projects/:id as well.

You can check in your projects controller whether the params[:user_id] exists or not and take necessary action.